# On workbook open, Excel Macro to refresh all data connections sheets and pivot tables and then export the pivot to csv

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel File which has CSV Data sources and Pivot tables, I want to refresh all the data sources and pivot tables automatically and export one pivot table as CSV on opening the excel file.

I tried the below code, but this code export the CSV file before the data getting refreshed.

please help with a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Run "Macro1"
End Sub


Sub Macro1()

 Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook
 Dim SaveToDirectory As String

 SaveToDirectory = "C:\Macro\"

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws In Sheets(Array("locationwise"))
     ws.Copy
     Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
     With newWb
        .SaveAs SaveToDirectory & ws.Name, xlCSV
        .Close (False)
     End With
 Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `DoEvents` should do the trick! ;)

Try this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    DoEvents
    Run "Macro1"
End Sub
```

And if it's not, just add this line after the `DoEvents` :

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

This will put on hold the execution of the code, here for 5 seconds!

---

If you want to launch the save parts once a specific range has been modified, place your that code into the **sheet** module :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(Rg_To_Check)) Is Nothing Then
    'Not in range
Else
    'In range to check
   Run "Macro1"
End If
End Sub
```

And get rid of the `Run "Macro1"` in the `Workbook_Open()` event.

---

Also, be careful, because your last line is `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` you won't have alerts afterwards, you should use it like this instead :

```
Sub Macro1()

 Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook
 Dim SaveToDirectory As String

 SaveToDirectory = "C:\Macro\"

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws In Sheets(Array("locationwise"))
     ws.Copy
     Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
     With newWb
        .SaveAs SaveToDirectory & ws.Name, xlCSV
        .Close (False)
     End With
 Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, i tried it, the 'Application.wait' command works. but what if my data is huge and the refreshing time takes more than 5 seconds? i will not be able to freeze the hold time because i do not know how much time it is going to take for refreshing huge data each time. please advice.

Comment: The `DoEvents` wasn't enough? Because most of the time, it should be! If it is not, deactivate the **background refresh** for your connections and this will work smoothly. And if it is still not enough, you'll have to try with a longer wait time I'm afraid...

Comment: i have deactivated the background refresh and tried. it is not working. i think i need to work on longer time wait.is there any alternative solution for this? can we export only when there is a change on a particular cell value?

Comment: i used application.intersect, thank you very much. it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help! ;)